# How to display a block view on demand triggered by clicking content of another view?

Tags: views, 8, blocks

A Link from a field value (view 1)  to another view (view 2) with contextual filtering works as well, if the second view is a page view.
But what about, if the second view should be a block view, only displaying after clicking on the link in view 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link just takes you to a different page. Since blocks are associated to pages, you just need to link to a page to which the block is associated.

Linking to the same page that should then show the block is not possible, since blocks appear right when the page is shown. There isn't a way to delay the block appearing on pages.